# MLlib ALS cannot delete checkpoint RDDs Wrong FS: hdfs://[url] expected: file:///

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, apache-spark-mllib

I am using Spark MLlib's ALS class to train a MatrixFactorizationModel. I have setup a HDFS for checkpointing intermediate rdds (as suggested by ALS class). The rdds are begin saved but I get an exception when it tries to delete them again: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://[url], expected: file:///`
Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://[url], expected: file:///
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:642)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:69)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:516)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.delete(ChecksumFileSystem.java:528)
at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ALS.scala:568)
at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ALS.scala:566)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(ALS.scala:566)
at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS$$anonfun$train$1.apply$mcVI$sp(ALS.scala:602)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS$.train(ALS.scala:596)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS.run(ALS.scala:219)
at adapters.ALSAdapter.run(ALSAdapter.java:59) ...
```

The culprit seems to be:

```
at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS.scala 568
FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration).delete(new Path(file), true)
```

which appears to return a `RawLocalFilesystem` instead of a distributed filesystem object.
I have not touched `sc.hadoopConfiguration`. The only interaction I've had is to call `myJavaStreamingContext.checkpoint(hdfs://[url + directory]);`.

Is there anything further I need to do client side to setup sc.hadoopConfiguration or would the problem be hdfs server side?

I was using spark 1.3.1 but tried 1.4.1 and the problem still persists.

Comment: You are trying to read or save a Model I suppose, right?

Comment: Hi eliasah. No, in the background, ALS creates intermediate RDDs when processing. These are what are checkpointed. From the ALS source:

    "Checkpointing helps with recovery (when nodes fail) and StackOverflow exceptions caused by long lineage. It also helps with eliminating temporary shuffle files on disk, which can be important when there are many ALS iterations."
I was coming across a Stackoverflow exception.

Comment: I know what checkpoints are. I was just wondering how you are performing them? and where is your cluster running?

Comment: ALS.run(...) from the Spark MLlib library is doing the checkpointing. My only involvement is calling `myJavaStreamingContext.checkpoint(hdfs://[url + directory]);` to specify the location to save the files. Spark is running locally and HDFS is running on a remote machine (single node).

Answer (score 0):

your sc.hadoopConfiguration is using local filesystem ("fs.default.name" = file:///) and despite specifying explicitly the checkpoint location, the ALS code uses sc.hadoopConfiguration to determine filesystem (e.g. for deleting previous checkpoints if applicable et al)

you can try
set sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.default.name", hfds://xx:port)
set sc.setCheckpointDir(yourCheckpointDir)
and just call checkpoint with no explicit filesystem path or see if setCheckpointInterval will work for you (i.e. let ALS take care of checkpointing)

you can add hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml to spark classpath if you don't want sc.hadoopConfiguration.set in code